# Site Prism, Capybara: Selector with variable

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, pageobjects, site-prism

I'm mucking around with the [site_prism](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism) to implement a Page Object Model in capybara. It looks very interesting.

How would I specify a selector such as "[data-id='x']" where x is an integer? Something like this:

```
class Home < SitePrism::Page
  set_url "http://www.example.com"
  element :row, "[data-id='@id']"
end
```

And then in my tests:

```
Then /^the home page should contain a row$/ do
  @home.should have_row 1234
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because SitePrism sets the element locator when the element is defined, what you've suggested doesn't work. To achieve what you've asked for, take a look at the following:

```
class Home < SitePrism::Page
  elements :rows, "tr[data-id]"

  def row_ids
    rows.map {|row| row['data-id']}
  end
end
```

Instead of mapping a single row, they're all mapped (using `elements` instead of `element`). A separate method called `row_ids` collects all of the rows that have 'data-id' value, maps all those values into a new array, and returns that new array.

The tests would then contain something like:

```
Then /^the home page should contain a row$/ do
  @home.row_ids.should include @id
end
```

...which will check that there is a row with an ID that matches `@id`.

Not as pretty, but it should work.

Comment: Cheers Nat. You wrote the gem, so you should know! Ha!

Answer (score 3):

Or, if you prefer this way, you can go 1 step further to what Nat suggested and define a row element as a simple method, which then can take id as an argument:

```
class Home < SitePrism::Page
    elements :rows, "tr[data-id]"

    def row_with_id(id)
         rows.find {|row| row['data-id'] == id.to_s}
    end
end
```

and then in your step definition

```
Then /^the home page should contain a row$/ do
    @home.row_with_id(1234).should_not be_nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the following - its a hack and by no means following page object pattern. But i couldn't work out the answers from above.

### My feature:

```
 Then I click on book 3 from the list
```

....

### My step looks something like this:

```
 Then /^I click on book (.*) from the list$/ do |index|
   page.method_find(index)
 end
```

### In my page object class:

```
  def method_find(index)
    find(div > div > span.nth-child({index})).click
  end
```